# Windows Phone 8.1 with remote MySQL without serverside php?

Tags: mysql, windows-phone-8.1

I have remote web MySQL database, which is only database without hosting. So, there is no ftp server, just remote database. Is there any way to get and insert data into/from my remote MySQL without php? I have read many posts, but many of them are old so I thought that maybe there is some new solution for situation like this, I mean some connectors or something like that. Without that I see two options: a) create hosting so I could write some services and create communication from WP8.1 app to server (php) and server side service would "speek" to database in the same hosting. b) create hosting, create php there and communicate with my db on the other place. Like wp app <-> hosting php <-> my database on internet.

WP app is for personal use only, only for me. So, I am not affraid of other users. The data received from DB is only String, while data send to db is object with String, double and Data attributes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the database is only for your use, why not include it as part of the app, as a sqlite db, or even (if you're using the Silverlight variant of Windows Phone apps) using Linq to SQL?

Comment: Well, I have created Java application with data analysis, charts and so on. I will use it for my own finansial data overview, balances and so on. I thought that I could create simple app for my Nokia Lumia 930, so I could insert my expenses almost instantly. But I see that I will use it old way.